# Reference request for Infinitary operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

Please suggest any introductory book , or article or some online resources form which I can learn about "Infinitary Operations " on sets .

Answer (score 1):

Both Birkhoff's [**Lattice Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821810251) and Sikorski's [**Boolean Algebras**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000BNXRD) have a lot of material on infinitary operations, as well as Kuratowski/Mostowski's [**Set Theory, with an Introduction to Descriptive Set Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0720404703) (2nd edition). These are classic books that most university libraries have. I saw a freely available digitized copy of Sikorski's book on the internet, but I don't know if it's a *legal copy*, so I'm not giving the URL here.